# if $f_n\to f$ uniformly in $[a,b]$ then $f\in BV$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, bounded-variation

While preparing to test in calculus I found the question above:

> Let $f_n(x)\to f$ uniformlly on $[a,b]$. Prove or give counterexample: if $\forall n\in\mathbb N f_n(x)\in BV$ and $\exists M>0$ s.t $\displaystyle V_a^b f_n\le M$ then $f\in BV$

I am really ashamed to say I don't have any ideas how to solve the question. Even though I think it's correct. First I think we need to define a partition on $[a,b]$ by $x_0<x_1<...<x_n$. Since $\forall n,f_n\in BV, |f_n(x_i)-f_n(x_{i-1})|<V_a^bf_n\le M$ Then we need to prove $V_{a}^bf=q<\infty$, which means taking sup for the expressions (created by paritions) in form of $\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}|f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|$. I thought changing the expression to $$\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^{n}|f(x_i)-f_n(x_i)+f_n(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|\le \sum_{i=0}^{n}|f_n(x_i)-f_(x_i)|+|f_n(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|$$. The first part is final and defined but I don't know how to manage with the second part ($|f_n(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})|$). How can I solve the question?

Comment: You're on the right track. But you need to add another well-chosen $0$: In your original, put in $-f_n(x_{i-1})+f_n(x_{i-1})$.

Comment: See [this](http://www.math.rochester.edu/people/grads/clungstr/real_analysis/hwset6.pdf) Exercise 2.4 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take limits instead. Let $x_0 < \cdots < x_k$ be a partition of $[a,b]$. Then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k |f_n(x_{i}) - f_n(x_{i-1})| \le V_a^b f_n \le M
$$
for every index $n$, which implies that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^k |f(x_{i}) - f(x_{i-1})| \le  M
$$
by taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ of the finite sum on the left. Note that $f_n \to f$ pointwise is all that is required. Now take the supremum over all partitions to get $V_a^b f \le M$.

Comment: Why the first equalation implies that the second is correct?

Comment: By taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ of the finite sum on the left.

Comment: And the fact that upper bounds are preserved under limits.